Is there any way to do a "hole punch" effect in CSS
An effect I'd really like to be able to replicate is a "hole punch". Sort of like clipping, but through another element.
It is possible to fake this effect when the background spans the entire viewport, but I have not found a way to do it when the background is, say, a card.
The below is an example of what I'd like it to look like:


html {
  height: 100%;
  --backround: linear-gradient(15deg, red, blue);
}

body {
  background-image: var(--backround);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

article {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 505px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: static;
  background: var(--backround) fixed;
  color: transparent;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 100%;
  background-clip: text;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="card">
      <article>
        <h1>01AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
        <h1>02AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
        <h1>03AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
        <h1>04AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
        <h1>05AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
        <h1>06AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
        <h1>07AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
        <h1>08AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
        <h1>09AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
        <h1>10AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
        <h1>11AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
        <h1>12AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      </article>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>



But on a "card" the below is the best I can do, where it is clear the text colour does not match up with the background. More changes will exacerbate that mismatch.


html {
  height: 100%;
  --backround: linear-gradient(15deg, red, blue);
}

.card {
  display: block;
  padding: 5em 10em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: fit-content;
  background-image: var(--backround);
}

article {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 505px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: static;
  background: var(--backround) fixed;
  color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
<main>
  <div class="card">
    <article>
      <h1>01AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      <h1>02AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      <h1>03AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      <h1>04AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      <h1>05AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      <h1>06AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      <h1>07AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      <h1>08AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      <h1>09AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      <h1>10AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      <h1>11AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
      <h1>12AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
    </article>
  </div>
</main>



The fixed background of the text scales to the viewport, not the card.
Is there any way to go about that?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#additional_notes

A few things to remember about specificity:
Specificity only applies when the same element is targeted by multiple declarations in the same cascade layer or origin. Specificity

only matters for declarations of the same importance and same origin
and cascade layer. If matching selectors are in different origins, the
cascade determines which declaration takes precedence.
When two selectors in the same cascade layer and origin have the same specificity, scoping proximity is then calculated; the ruleset

with the lowest scoping proximity wins. See How @scope conflicts are
resolved for more details and an example.
If scope proximity is also the same for both selectors, source order then comes into play. When all else is equal, the last selector

wins.
As per CSS rules, directly targeted elements will always take precedence over rules which an element inherits from its ancestor.

Proximity of elements in the document tree has no effect on the 
specificity.


I that the CSS probably worked or came close but got nullified by one of these rules.
